# I found a linear function $f$ with "weird" multiplication $f(a)f(b)=f(af(b))=af(f(b))$. Is it of any use?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

I found a function $f:Z \rightarrow Q$ (the domain may be extended to $Q$) such that, if $a+b=c \in Z$, we can perform $f(a)+f(b)=f(c)$, and this function has the properties:

1. $xf(a)+yf(b)=f(xa+yb)$      ***(very similar to Z)***
2. $f(a)f(b)=f(af(b))=af(f(b))$    ***(a weird multiplication)***
3. $nf(x)=f(nx)$       ***(homogeneous)***

**Question** 
Can you find any good use of this?

Comment: *$f(f(b)$) in property 2 is composition of function

Comment: $f$ has to be of the form $f(x)=kx$ for some constant $k$, doesn't it? There are lots of good uses for a function $f(x)=kx$.

Comment: @Rahul Yes. Incidentally, the original version of the post didn't have the word linear in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By property 3 alone, we already have $f\left(n\right)=f\left(n*1\right)=nf\left(1\right)$, so this map just scales the integers (and possibly flips them if $f(1)<0$). Properties 0. (the $f(a)+f(b)=f(c)$ thing) and 1. and 2. all hold automatically.

There are tons of things to learn in mathematics that build upon examples like this one, so I encourage you to keep thinking and also to keep reading/studying.

For instance, your function is a [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences) from the integers to the rationals over the integers (to anyone worried that the integers aren't a field, they're still a ring so we have [a module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics))). It's therefore also a [group homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) from the integers to the [additive group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_group) of the rationals.